# How to insert a json array into a mongodb collection in Apache Nifi using PutMongo?

Tags: mongodb, etl, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I am trying to insert a json array into mongodb using Putmongo processor in Apache nifi. But I'm getting an error:

```
error: current bson type is an array and not a document
```

Here is my json:

```
[{"Name":"computer","TotalRevenue":15000},
{"Name":"music","TotalRevenue":1500},
{"Name":"space","TotalRevenue":5000}][{"Name":"a rehman","company":"music","revenue":500},
{"Name":"bill gates","company":"computer","revenue":6000},
{"Name":"elon must","company":"space","revenue":5000},
{"Name":"john lenin","company":"music","revenue":1000},
{"Name":"steve jobs","company":"computer","revenue":9000}]
```

Also, I'm attaching the Putmongo configuration [image: PutMongo cofiguration]

Here is my Full Apache Flow :

GetFile CSV -> ConvertRecord to Json -> QueryRecord -> MergeContent -> PutMongo

Answer (score 0):

PutMongo does not accept an array of JSON objects. So I split the array into individual JSON objects using the SplitJson processor. And later merged it using MergeContent processor to get the desired results.